# Get File Permissions and Parent Directory

Tags: android, bash, sed, sqlite

How can I get the `$DIR` and `$OPERM` to return the correct values?

I am attempting to grab all sqlite3 databases and while the all list if I `echo $i;`, I need to work on:

1. the parent folder (in order to do what I need with $i)
2. store the original file permissions for later use on said file.

So far, all I've managed to do is get this to echo the words **sed** and **stat**

```
for i in $($BB find /system -iname "*.db") 
    do \
        ORPERM=(stat -c "%a" $i);
        DIR=(sed 's|/[^/]*$||' $i);
        echo $DIR;
        echo $OPERM;
done;
```

p.s.   $BB = busybox

Comment: You missed the `$` sign: `ORPERM=$( stat -c "%a" $i );`, `DIR=$( sed 's|/[^/]*$||' $i );`

Comment: That's getting me an endless loop of nonsense.  I think the `sed` statement is searching in the files and dumping out the textual content...

Comment: `dirname $i` did the trick

Comment: @nsilent22 can you post yours as the answer, add in the `dirname $i` instead of the `sed` as well for others who'll read the q&a please

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was on vacation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the $ sign:

```
ORPERM=$( stat -c "%a" $i );
DIR=$( dirname $i );
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11701734)

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat: You didn't read the comments below the question, did you?

Comment: I think if this is a pretty clear answer for the question, you wouldn't post it as a comment before, you know it is just a comment, and if this is his whole problem he has to remove the question but a question remains here as a wrong typing, in my opinion it is not very helpful for another users

Comment: If you didn't notice I posted it as an answer because of clear OP request.